# Storing records in array

Tags: php, mysql

I have little problem. 
I want to save records from database in array. 
But I don't know it doesn't work :/
I would be grateful for help.

```
<?php
require ('common.php');

$query ="SELECT gallery_cat_id, gallery_cat_name FROM gallery_catalogs";
try{
    $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
            catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        die('Nie nawiązano połączenia: ' . $ex->getMessage());              
    }


    $album=array();
    while($row=$stmt->mysql_fetch_assoc())
        {
        $album[$row['gallery_cat_id']]=$row['gallery_cat_name'];
        }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($album);

?>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What's the error you are getting? At what line are you getting it? What about warnings? etc...

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **mysqli** with the object oriented interface with prepared statements, you can use  `->fetch()`:

```
$query = "SELECT gallery_cat_id, gallery_cat_name FROM gallery_catalogs";

try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    die('Nie nawiązano połączenia: ' . $ex->getMessage());              
}

$album = array();

$stmt->bind_result($gallery_cat_id, $gallery_cat_name);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $album[$gallery_cat_id] = $gallery_cat_name;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($album);
```

Or if you have the `mysqlnd` driver , you can use  `->get_result()`, then use `->fetch_assoc()`:

```
$query ="SELECT gallery_cat_id, gallery_cat_name FROM gallery_catalogs";

try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    die('Nie nawiązano połączenia: ' . $ex->getMessage());              
}

$album = array();

$results = $stmt->get_result();

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $album[$row['gallery_cat_id']] = $row['gallery_cat_name'];
}
// i prefer this one
```

So this line doesn't make sense:

```
$stmt->mysql_fetch_assoc() // ??? statement object mixed up with old API?
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code starting from the array $album

Try this:

```
$album=array();
while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) )
{
    $album[$row->gallery_cat_id] = $row;   // $row -> will store both ID Value and the Category Name Value in the array..
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($album),'</pre>';     // to view the records fetched in preformatted way
```

Fetching in object is much better than fetching in procedural way..